# (Axios) HTTP POST request failed after two minutes, Laravel 5 + VueJS

Tags: mysql, vue.js, laravel-5, axios, google-cloud-storage

I am trying to replicate data in the database for a specific user. It is almost 1000 rows that should be replicated. But my request gets failed with Empty response after 2 min. you can see in the picture. I am not able to identify the issue. Guide me if anyone has already solved this kind of issue.

[image]

My database is hosted on Google Cloud Storage and I am using MySQL.

This is my controller method:

```
   public function createDataForManyToMany (Request $request)
   {
      $rows = TableA::where('id_analysis', 
      $request->analysis_id)->get();

      $files_data = TableB::Where('id_analysis', 
      $request->analysis_id)->get();

      foreach ($rows as $row)
      {
          $row->input_files()->saveMany($files_data);
      }

      return response()->json([
          'status' => 'ok',
          'analysis_id' => $request->analysis_id
      ]);

  }
```

My Axios post request:

```
axios.post('/app/create-det-infiles-data', { '_token': this.csrf_token, 'analysis_id': res.data.analysis_id})
        .then( res => {
                if (res.data.status === 'ok') {
                    this.signupTried = false
                    this.emailSent = true
                 }
```

Vue Component:

```
       <template>
<div class="fullwidth-container">
    <div class="login-container">
        <v-card class="login_form elevation-9">
            <form class="login">
                <input type="hidden" name="_token" :value="csrf_token"/>
                <div class="header">
                    <h1>PIX2MAP SignUp</h1>
                </div>
                <v-text-field
                    color="dark"
                    prepend-icon="person"
                    :label="$t('name')"
                    required
                    :error-messages="nameErrors"
                    v-model="name">
                </v-text-field>
                <v-text-field
                    color="dark"
                    prepend-icon="email"
                    label="Email"
                    required
                    :error-messages="emailErrors"
                    v-model="email">
                </v-text-field>
                <v-text-field
                    color="dark"
                    prepend-icon="vpn_key"
                    :append_icon="show_pass ? 'visibility_off' : 'visibility'"
                    :type="show_pass ? 'text' : 'password'"
                    :error-messages="passwordErrors"
                    required
                    :label="$t('password')"
                    v-model="password"
                    @click:append="show_pass = !show_pass">
                </v-text-field>
                <v-text-field
                    class="pwd-confirm"
                    color="dark"
                    :append_icon="show_pass ? 'visibility_off' : 'visibility'"
                    :type="show_pass2 ? 'text' : 'password'"
                    :error-messages="repeatPasswordErrors"
                    required
                    :label="$t('repeat_password')"
                    v-model="password2"
                    @click:append="show_pass = !show_pass">
                </v-text-field>
                <v-layout row style="margin: 0">
                    <v-flex shrink style="margin-top: 0">
                        <v-checkbox
                                v-model="termsAccepted"
                                :label="`I accept the `"
                                :error-messages="acceptAgreementError"
                        >
                        </v-checkbox>
                    </v-flex>
                    <v-flex grow text-xs-left style="margin-top: 0">
                         <a href='#' style="color: #0f81cc; margin-left: 5px; padding-top: 5px;" @click="changeState">contract</a>
                    </v-flex>
                </v-layout>
                <v-btn class="btn-signup" color="accent" @click="doSignup"
                       :disabled="formFilled"
                        >Confirm <span class="float-right" :class="{'fas':signupTried, 'fa-spinner':signupTried, 'fa-spin':signupTried}"></span>
                </v-btn>
                <p class="privacy">{{ $t('form_privacy') }}</p>
            </form>
        </v-card>
        <div class="back">
            <v-btn flat @click="$emit('back')"><v-icon>arrow_back</v-icon>{{ $t('back_button') }}</v-btn>
        </div>
    </div>
    <v-dialog
            v-model="dialog"
            max-width="650"
    >
        <v-card>
            <v-card-title class="headline grey lighten-2">{{ contractTitile }}
                <span style="margin-left: auto"><v-icon right @click="dialog = !dialog">fas fa-times</v-icon></span>
            </v-card-title>

            <v-card-text >
                    {{ contractBody }}
            </v-card-text>

            <v-card-actions>
                <v-spacer></v-spacer>
            </v-card-actions>
        </v-card>
    </v-dialog>

    <v-snackbar
            v-if="signupTried"
            v-model="snackbar"
            dark
            :bottom="y === 'bottom'"
            :timeout="timeout"
            :left="x === 'left'"
            :color="color"
            :multi-line="mode === 'multi-line'"
            :right="x === 'right'"
            :top="y === 'top'"
            :vertical="mode === 'vertical'"
    >
        {{ text }}
    </v-snackbar>
    <v-snackbar
            v-if="emailSent"
            v-model="emailSnackbar"
            :bottom="y === 'bottom'"
            :timeout="timeout"
            :left="x === 'left'"
            :multi-line="mode === 'multi-line'"
            :right="x === 'right'"
            :top="y === 'top'"
            :color="color"
            :vertical="mode === 'vertical'"
    >
        {{ emailSentMessage }}
    </v-snackbar>
</div>
</template>

<script>
import { required, email } from 'vuelidate/lib/validators'
import {TITLE, BODY_TEXT} from '../contract' 
import axios from 'axios'

export default {
props: {
    csrf_token: String,
    name: String,
    email: String,
},
data: () => ({
    contractTitile: TITLE,
    contractBody: BODY_TEXT,
    show_pass: false,
    show_pass2: false,
    name: '',
    email: '',
    password: '',
    password2: '',
    signupTried: false,
    emailExist: false,
    dialog: false,
    termsAccepted: false,


    snackbar: true,
    y: 'bottom',
    x: null,
    mode: '',
    timeout: 10000,
    color: '#fff',
    text: 'This process will take some time, please! be patience.',

    emailSent: false,
    emailSnackbar: true,
    emailSentMessage: 'We have sent you instructions, please verify your account by visiting your email.'
}),
validations: {
    name: {
        required
    },
    email: {
        required,
        email
    },
    password: {
        required
    },
    password2: {
        required
    },
    termsAccepted: {
        required
    }
},

methods: {
    async doSignup () {
        this.signupTried = true
        if (this.$v.name.required && this.$v.email.required && this.$v.email.email && this.$v.password.required && this.termsAccepted ) {
             axios.post('/app/register', { '_token': this.csrf_token, 'name': this.name,'email': this.email, 'password': this.password })
                    .then(res => {
                        if (res.data.status === 'ok') {
                             axios.post('/app/create-in-files-data', { '_token': this.csrf_token, 'analysisIds': res.data.analysis_ids})
                                    .then(resp => {
                                        if (resp.data.status === 'ok') {
                                             axios.post('/app/create-mo-files-data', { '_token': this.csrf_token, 'analysisIds': resp.data.analysis_ids})
                                                    .then( res => {
                                                        if (res.data.status === 'ok') {
                                                            // window.location = '/'
                                                            // this.signupTried = false
                                                            // this.emailSent = true
                                                             axios.post('/app/create-det-infiles-data', { '_token': this.csrf_token, 'analysis_id': res.data.analysis_id})
                                                                    .then( res => {
                                                                        if (res.data.status === 'ok') {
                                                                            this.signupTried = false
                                                                            this.emailSent = true
                                                            //              await axios.post('/app/create-det-mofiles-data', { '_token': this.csrf_token, 'analysis_id': res.data.analysis_id, demo: true})
                                                            //                      .then(async res => {
                                                            //                          if (res.data.status === 'ok') {
                                                            //                              this.showSpinner = false
                                                            //                              window.location = '/'
                                                            //                          } else {
                                                            //                              console.log('Files not created')
                                                            //                              this.showSpinner = false
                                                            //                              this.$emit('forgotPw', {email: this.email});
                                                            //                          }
                                                            //                      })
                                                            //                      .catch(e => {
                                                            //                          console.log('2nd error', e)
                                                            //                      })
                                                                        } else {
                                                                            console.log('Files not created')
                                                                            this.showSpinner = false
                                                                            this.$emit('forgotPw', {email: this.email});
                                                                        }

                                                                    })
                                                                    .catch(e => {
                                                                        console.log('2nd error', e)
                                                                    })
                                                        } else {
                                                            console.log('Signup Failed')
                                                            this.signupTried = false
                                                            this.$emit('forgotPw', {email: this.email});
                                                        }
                                                    })
                                                    .catch(e => {
                                                        console.log('2nd error', e)
                                                    })

                                        } else {
                                            console.log('Files not created')
                                            this.showSpinner = false
                                            this.$emit('forgotPw', {email: this.email});
                                        }
                                    })
                                    .catch(e => {
                                        console.log('Error: ', e)
                                    })

                        } else {
                            this.showSpinner = false
                            this.$emit('forgotPw', {email: this.email});
                        }
                    })
        }
    },

    changeState () {
        this.dialog = !this.dialog
    }
},

computed: {
    nameErrors () {
        if (this.signupTried && this.name.length == 0 && !this.$v.name.required) return [this.$t('name_required')]
    },
    emailErrors () {
        const errors = []
        if (this.signupTried && !this.$v.email.required) errors.push(this.$t('email_required'))
        if (!this.$v.email.email) errors.push(this.$t('not_valid_email'))
        if (this.emailExist) errors.push(this.$t('existing_email'))
        return errors
    },
    passwordErrors () {
        if (this.signupTried && !this.$v.password.required) return [this.$t('password_required')]
    },
    repeatPasswordErrors () {
        if (this.signupTried && !this.$v.password2.required) return [this.$t('password_required')]
        if (this.password2 != this.password) return [this.$t('passwords_not_equal')]
    },
    acceptAgreementError () {
        if (this.signupTried && !this.$v.termsAccepted.required) return [this.$t('agreement_required')]
    },
    formFilled () {
        if (!this.$v.name.required || !this.$v.email.required || !this.$v.password.required || !this.$v.password2.required || !this.termsAccepted || (this.password != this.password2))
        {
            return true
        } else {
            return false
        }
    }
}
}
</script>

<style scoped lang="stylus">
@import '../../stylus/theme.styl'

.fullwidth-container {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
background: $bg-login;
position: absolute;
top: 0px;
left: 0px;
z-index: 2;

.login-container {
    position: relative;
    width: 500px;
    top: 25px;
    margin: auto;

    .login_form {
        padding: 16pt;
        text-align: center;
        height: 800px;

        * {
            margin-top: 24pt;
        }

        .header {
            margin: 24pt;
        }

        .i-am {
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: row;
            align-items: center;

            * {
                margin-top: 0pt;
            }

            span {
                width: 8%;
            }

            .i-am-text {
                margin-right: 20px;
            }

            .i-am-select {
                margin-left: 5%;
            }
        }

        .btn-signup {
            margin-left: auto;
            margin-right: auto;
            width: 80%;
        }

        .privacy {
            margin-top: 8pt;
            font-style: italic;
        }

        .pwd-confirm {
            margin-left: 7%;
        }

        .checkboxAccept {
            display: inline;
        }

        .float-right {
            margin-top: -3px;
            margin-left: 5px;
            color: #fff;
            font-size: 18px;
        }
    }
   }
  }
 </style>
```

Comment: can you share your controller method with the HTTP request with axios, please?

Comment: @Thamerbelfkih I had added my controller and post request in my question. please have a look at that.

Comment: for the axios post, please post all the vue component

Comment: Component added. @Thamerbelfkih

Comment: Have you seen any errors on your Cloud SQL instance? you can chekc your logs as per [this](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/instance-info#mysqllogs) and [this](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/diagnose-issues#query-logs).

Comment: @Thamerbelfkih you can also check your runtime logs (you may be using GAE, GCE or other).

Comment: Here is an error found in laravel logs:

Comment: PDOException(code: 2002): SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused at user/project/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connectors/Connector.php:67, ErrorException(code: 0): PDO::__construct(): MySQL server has gone away at user/projectvendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connectors/Connector.php:67) @MikePerezOntiveros

Answer (score 0):

This issue might be caused due to MySQL instance is reaching the time out limit for your query.

In Cloud SQL you can try to modify the flag “wait_timeout” and set a bigger value, for example 50000.

Check this [link](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/flags#setting_a_database_flag) as a reference to set a flag in Cloud SQL instance.